# Paginate results of a query by category

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am attempting to create a query to grab 25  forum threads (per page) for a specific forum category, and then attempting to order them by ID descending to show the newest posts first, though I can't seem to get it to work...

Here is the PHP & SQL

```
$category =  $_GET['category'];
$show_thr_max =  $_GET['thr'];
$show_thr_min =  $show_thr_max - 24;

$threadsq = "SELECT * FROM `forum_post` WHERE `post_cate_id` = '$category' AND `id` BETWEEN '$show_thr_min' AND '$show_thr_max'";
$threadsr = mysqli_query($con, $threadsq);
```

`$category` is the ID of the category to grab the related threads from,

`$show_thr_ max` is set to 25, incrementing by 25 as each page passes, it's the max range of threads to grab.

`$shrow_thr_min` sets the min range (24 less then _max) of threads to grab.

The query is grabbing the threads between the range, they're from the correct category, THOUGH it's grabbing the first 25 it can find, not the 25 with the highest id.

So page one would show ids 25 through to 1, instead of 91 through to 66, which is the desired result

I know there is a precedence table in SQL for clauses, could this be the cause? Ordering before all conditions have been met?

thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: 1. create a query to retrieve ALL the records ordered as you want. 2. apply LIMIT to restrict the result to the next N records. Using the ID you may retrieve less results (i.e. if you deleted a record)

Comment: `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` would work.

Comment: The comments above and the answer by Tim suggest the proper way to do this, but the *symptom* you describe suggests that your min and max are not set properly, in which case their solution also wouldn't work. You need to fix that problem as well, in other words, find out why `$_GET['thr']` doesn't give you the value you expect.

Comment: That works, thank you guys! @GolezTrol, min-max variables are set  correctly. Page two max-min are 50-26, it was the first thing I checked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get away with just using a `LIMIT/OFFSET` query here:

```
SELECT *
FROM forum_post
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 25
OFFSET 25;     -- replace 25 with whatever page you want
```

Some are critical of using limit/offset for pagination, because of that sometimes new data can come into a previous page, throwing off the paging logic.  However, in your case, posts which were made in the past cannot be added or changed (most likely).  So, in this case, limit/offset should be a viable option.

If you really did want to handle your own pagination, then using the `id` might be problematical, because there is no guarantee that it would be completely sequential (unless you strictly controlled it yourself).

Comment: Thank you Tim! This works perfectly, but it looks as if with moderation (deleting threads) it could prove to be an issue a while down the line when ids aren't as well ordered :/  Do you think this could be an issue?

Comment: That depends on what behavior you want in that case.  Tell us what should happen if a user is on the second page, and a moderator kills a few posts from the previous first page.

Comment: So deleting a thread drops the row from the DB, along with its ID... I think I was overthinking my question! I believe the query will just grab the 25 id's regardless of whether they are id'd as 25 26 27 or  24 29 or 31 until it has the 25 it needs, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right...it doesn't care about the `id` value, just how many records there are.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for the help :) Apologises for the silly question, I am rather new to "complex" (to me at least, LOL) queries.

Comment: If you see flaws in my answer, come back and comment about them.  There are several ways to do what you want.  I gave what I think is the easiest solution to implement.

Comment: Will do! Thank you again. Greatly appreciate it.